# how to use contains with group of words that have html space between them

Tags: jquery

how do i search for the entire span word phrase

I want to find all spans that contain this exact wording

```
<span>Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft</span>
```

tried this

```
$('span:contains("Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft")').remove();

$('span:contains("Select Player To Pre-Draft")').remove();

$('span:contains("Select/&nbsp;/Player/&nbsp;/To/&nbsp;/Pre-Draft")').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clear_all(){
 $('div').each(function(){
  var this_html=$(this).html();
  this_html=this_html.replace(new RegExp('<span>Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft</span>', 'g'), '');
  $(this).html(this_html);
 });
}

clear_all();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
   <span>Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span>Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft</span> test1
</div>
<div>
   <span>Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft</span> test2
</div>
<div>
   <span>Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft</span>test3<span>Select&nbsp;Player&nbsp;To&nbsp;Pre-Draft</span>test4
</div>

<!--input type="button" value="Clear All" onclick="clear_all();"-->
```

Comment: just looking to remove this on page load , no buttons  https://jsfiddle.net/dc6g9o4z/34/

Comment: Correction for auto clear...